# How do I point pip3 to the correct PATH to display version

Tags: python, bash, pip

I am having problems using `pip3` on my Windows 10 machine.

I have python3 and pip3 installed.

pip and pip2 point to my Python2.7 versions and provide the correct output when I use which pip and pip --version.

My Python3 installation is in a different directory. Although I have both Python 2 and Python 3 paths correctly saved in my Environment Variables I cannot install modules using pip3 nor can I get the correct version output for pip3.

As a matter of fact now I cant even get `pip --version` working now...

Here is the out put of my bash terminal to see the issue better:

[image: Bash Terminal]

How do I get pip3 working for Python3 module installations?

Ultimately I am trying to use:

```
python3 -m pip3 install Flask
```

to install Flask for Python3.... with pip3...

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python3 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

left me with pip pointing to python3, a pip2 pointing to python2, and a pip3 pointing to python3.